# Distinct query of MongoDB not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymongo, python-3.6

```
try:
    uri = 'mongodb://' + uid_ + ':' + pwd_ + '@' + h + ':' + str(p_)
    client = MongoClient(uri)
    print("connected!")
    module_info = client[db1][t].distinct("module_name")
    for m in module_info:
       print(m)
except Exception as e:
    print (e)
```

Here I am trying to get a distinct value from column "module_name"
but while executing the query it throws me following error:

> connected!
>
> [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Comment: Is your mongo database server __running__ and listening for connections at `h:p_`?

Comment: yes it is listening

Comment: Are you able to run a mongo shell connected to the server? _i.e._ Run `mongo <your_DB_URI>` in powershell

Comment: yes I am able to do that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MongoClient()** class will immediately return the connection object and try to connect to the MongoDB. In your case even though it has reached connected print statement, The database connection would not have happened.
Try printing the connected nodes and check if the connection has happened. Sometimes the connection may take some time, try putting a sleep and check if the connection has happened or not

```
from time import sleep
try:
    uri = 'mongodb://' + uid_ + ':' + pwd_ + '@' + h + ':' + str(p_)
    client = MongoClient(uri)
    sleep(0.5)
    print("connected!", client.nodes)
except Exception as e:
    print (e)

try:
    module_info = client[db1][t].distinct("module_name")
    for m in module_info:
       print(m)
except Exception as e:
    print (e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
module_info = client[db1][t].find().distinct("module_name")
```

Comment: I think you have connection problem with mongoDb. Read from this link how to make connection 
 using mongoclient. 
 http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/authentication.html